# Mysql Select Statement isn't working

Tags: mysql

So maybe it's due to lack of sleep, but I am having a major brain malfunction and can't remember what is going wrong here. Here is my statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `county`, COUNT(*)
FROM `ips`
WHERE `county` != 'NULL' AND `county` != '' AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `pages`
WHERE (`timestamp` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(?)))
GROUP BY `county`
```

I'm expecting the results to be something like:

```
County | Number
Some county | 42
Other county | 27
```

My pages table has a timestamp of each time a page is viewed by a user, so if they viewed a page between the date, the county from the IP table is selected and the number of that total county is being populated as the num. I'm using PDO and i'm passing in two times that I've used `strtotime()` on.

I'm currently stuck. All help is apprieciated. Hopefully it's not some stupid little mistake that I've overlooked.

Comment: I get an empty set. The time stamps are correct. I use a year ago to today, and there are thousands of rows. I'm missing something, or doing something wrong. I'm just not sure.

Comment: `NULL` is not equal to **anything** (including another `NULL`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant compare null with `!=` you need to use is not null.

```
SELECT `county`, COUNT(*)
FROM `ips`
WHERE `county` IS NOT NULL AND `county` != '' AND
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `pages`
        WHERE (`timestamp` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(?) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(?)))
GROUP BY `county`
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is hardly needed when `GROUP`ed `BY` the same.

Comment: One more: in `EXISTS` query it does not make any sense to output any fields `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)` is enough.

Comment: Thank you. This works. Also, thank you for optimizing it better. I've never really understood why you select 1 but I do in this case.